# MongoDB emulate sequence object(not UUID)

Tags: mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

Is it possible in MongoDB to create/emulate something similar to a Postgres sequence database object?

I need this thread safe functionality in order to be able to ask it for next, unique `Long` value. I'm going to use this value as a surrogate key for my entities.

Also, I don't want to go with `UUID` because I have to expose these IDs within my web application url parameters and in case of `UUID` my urls look awful. I want to go with a plain Long values for IDs.

Comment: Efficient reliable generation of monotonically increasing unique integers in a distributed system is a hard problem. This is the reason why people use things like uuid/ObjectId.

Comment: Having said that, a naive implementation of a sequence is a simple `findAndModify` call. It does imply a separate call to fetch next id (meaning, your app just got at least two times slower)